# Javascript Regex: find & remove letters that repeat LESS THAN a certain number of times

Tags: javascript, regex

Say, for the string "lllrrrrrrrruuddddr", I need to remove those letters that repeat less than 4 times, ie, "lll" and "uu" and "r", resulting in "rrrrrrrrdddd".

So far I can only use an unweildy workaround by marking those letters repeating *at least* 4 times with certain special marks and removing all the rest, and then removing my special marks. It's far from elegant, and is prone to error if the original string happens to contain letters idential to my special mark.

Comment: Can you show your regex, how far you got? I'd think of [something like this](https://regex101.com/r/pqq60e/1/).

Comment: I replaced letters like .replace(/(l{4,})/g,'+++$1---'), and then repeated the same process on other letters. Sorry I forgot to mention in the question that there are only several possible letters in the string, so I did this very awkward process time and again, and then removed other letters, and then removed "+++" and "---". It's not a solution, just an ugly temp workaround.

Comment: I will study your code. I need to do some research to understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think of a [pattern like this (regex101)](https://regex101.com/r/pqq60e/2/). With Javascript [see this demo (tio.run)](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/j/vyyxSKFYwVZBPScnpwgKSktTgKBI3ZqLCyRVrFeUWpCTmJyqoa@hEZ2oWxWrGWNUbaxTq1kD5umnZ@qoqxiqawLVJ@fnFefnpOrl5KdrFGta//8PAA).

```
s = s.replace(/(([a-z])\2{3,})|[a-z]/gi,'$1');
```

Idea is to [capture](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) letters, that [repeat](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) 4 or more times in group 1 and replace left ones with empty.

Comment: Bobble Bubble, at first glance the code really confused me, because I'm only at beginner level with regex. Fortunately, the regex101 site offers explanation, which is really nice. I have just finished reading it, and this is really amazing. Thanks so much!

Comment: @M.X Glad it was helpful! Yea the Regex101 site has most useful explanation : ) The basic idea is to replace those captures with 4 or more by itself and if there is a match on the other side of the alternation `|[a-z]` capture group 1 is empty, thus removed.

Comment: The |[a-z] alternate and replacing it with empty is the real cool part! An eye opener for a noob!