# Javascript Regex: find & REPLACE letters that repeat LESS THAN a certain number of times

Tags: javascript, regex

This question is a derivative from another one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68282763/javascript-regex-find-remove-letters-that-repeat-less-than-a-certain-number-o):

Say, for the string "lllrrrrrrrruuddddr", how to replace those letters that repeat less than 4 times with "-", thus resulting in "---rrrrrrrr--dddd-".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is the simplest way.

- `[a-zA-Z]` matches a single ASCII letter
- `([a-zA-Z])` is a *capturing group*
- `\1` is a *backreference* that tells us to match again exactly what was matched by capturing group #1 again
- `\1*` tells us to match that backreference zero or more times

Then you just need this:

```js
function replaceRunsWithLengthLessThan( s, n, r ) {
    const replaced = typeof(s) !== "string"
      ? s
      : s.replace( rxSingleLetterRun, m => m.length < n ? r : m )
      ;
    return replaced;
  }
  const rxSingleLetterRun = /([a-zA-Z])\1*/ig;
```

which can be invoked as

```js
const orig = 'aaaa bbb cc d eeeeee'
const repl = replaceRunsWithLengthLessThan( orig, 4, '-');
```

and which produces the expected value: `aaaa - - - eeeeee`.

**Edited to note:** If you want to replace the short runs with as many dashes as the length of the run, you just need to change

```js
s.replace( rxSingleLetterRun, m => m.length < n ? r : m )
```

with

```js
s.replace( rxSingleLetterRun, m => m.length < n ? r.repeat(m.length) : m )
```

Comment: Since you're using the `i` flag anyway, it's safe to go with just `[a-z]` instead of `[a-zA-Z]`.

Comment: @Nicholas Carey: It's awesome! I was so lost about how to find the number of matched letters, and your code not only solved it but also taught me how to express the replacement string with a function!